# My Javascript only seems to work on my first entry in my Laravel foreach loop

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, foreach, local-storage

I have a foreach loop running in Laravel that has a dropdown in it. The dropdown is supposed to inform people about the status of a certain survey (Sent, not sent, received, etc). The idea being that the status of a certain survey is just stored locally. So even after a page refresh, the status would be remembered.

```
@foreach($surveys as $sur)
   <tr>
      <td style="padding:5px 25px 0 0;">{{$sur->titel}}</td>
      <td style="padding:5px 25px 0 0;">
         <select id="myDynamicSelectBox">
            <option>None</option>
            <option>Not send</option>
            <option>Sent</option>
            <option>Answer received</option>
         </select>
      </td>
@endforeach
```

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
const mySel = document.getElementById("myDynamicSelectBox");
mySel.addEventListener("change",function() {
  localStorage.setItem("selValue",this.value); // save it
});
let val = localStorage.getItem("selValue");
if (val) mySel.value=val; // set the dropdown
// trigger the change in case there are other events on the select
mySel.onchange(); 
</script>
```

So the problem that I'm facing, is that it does save the status of the first survey in the foreach loop. But for some reason the other surveys can't hold the values. Any ideas?

Thanks for your time,

Cheers,

Comment: id="myDynamicSelectBox"
id should be unique for each selector

Comment: so.. should I change the id to something else like class?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have many `select` with the same `ID`. Javascript looks the document for the first matching element having the necessary `ID` and stops the search. You should use `class` attribute for this purpose and find elements with `document.querySelector('select.someClassNameHere')` to get all the dropdown you need.

Comment: So I changed the ```id="myDynamicSelectBox"``` in ```select``` to ```class="myDynamicSelectBox"``` and in my script ```document.getElementById("myDynamicSelectBox");``` to ```document.querySelector('select.myDynamicSelectBox');``` but this seems to not work. Still can only save the first entry in my foreach loop.

Comment: In your code you have an array of elements after running `document.querySelector('select.myDynamicSelectBox');`. Next thing you have to do is to loop through that array of elements and attach eventListener to every element.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I have honestly no idea how I am supposed to do that.

Comment: It has not much difference from the code you provided in your questing. Start with `let items = document.querySelector('select.myDynamicSelectBox'); for(let i in items) { items[I].addEventListener('change', function() {}); }…` and don't be afraid to make experiments with it.

Comment: @RodionBaskakov `document.querySelector` returns a single element, **not** an array. `document.querySelectorAll` is what returns an array with all matching elements.

Comment: Right, so I changed out ```const mySel = document.getElementById("myDynamicSelectBox");
mySel.addEventListener("change",function() {
  localStorage.setItem("selValue",this.value); 
});``` to have it store an array and loop through it via ```let items = document.querySelectorAll('select.myDynamicSelectBox'); 
for(let i in items) { 
    items[I].addEventListener("change", function() {
        localStorage.setItem("selValue",this.value); 
    }); 
}``` sadly, it doesn't seem to store anything since it can't even hold the first value anymore. Should I return something after the for loop?

Comment: @RikRödel `items[I]` needs to be `items[i]`

Comment: That's what I assumed as well. Sadly. I tried that but that doesnt seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a unique value per ID of the select elements. I suggest you use the ID from the survey object as such:

```
@foreach($surveys as $sur)
<tr>
   <td style="padding:5px 25px 0 0;">{{$sur->titel}}</td>
   <td style="padding:5px 25px 0 0;">
      <select onChange="doStuff({{$sur->id}})" id="myDynamicSelectBox{{$sur->id}}">
         <option>None</option>
         <option>Not send</option>
         <option>Sent</option>
         <option>Answer received</option>
      </select>
   </td>
@endforeach
```

Then you handle your changes per event per survey id, since you are adding the listener in the HTML section, you no longer need to add it in the script. You only need to write the function itself, and make it take in the id you are using.

```
function doStuff(id){
     let selector = "myDynamicSelectBox"+id;
     let mySel = document.getElementById(selector);
     let stored = localStorage.getItem("selectedValues");
     let data;
     if(store){
         data = JSON.parse(stored);
     } else {
         data = {};
     }
     data[selector] = mySel.value; //or mySel.options[mySel.selectedIndex].value if using a real select element...
     localStorage.setItem("selectedValues", JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

That is how you save the data, now to load the data you need to write something that gets the propertioes out of the stored object. You can find that here on SO. Search for get properties from object. Then you loop over that list, and do the DOM changes you need.

```
function loadData(){
    let data = localStorage.getItem("selectedValues");
    if(data){
        let stored = JSON.parse(data);
        // get property names from stored.
        // loop over them and get the select elements by id given by the keys
        // assign values
        // other logic...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I have honestly no clue how I am supposed to translate that into my js..